# Dense function input shape mismatch with one hot encoded training data in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, one-hot-encoding

The target output training set is as below:
y_train = [0, 5, 3, 1]

The one hot encoded value is as below:

```python
Y_train = [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

       [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]

       [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]

       [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The number of classes in this target set is 4.
The dimension of individual one hot encoded value is 6.

When I mention the number of class value in the final output dense function of the keras sequential dl model I get following error message:

```python
*ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 4) but got array with shape (44833, 6)*
```

I tried to solve this problem by changing the target list values into an ordered list as below:

old_y_train = [0, 5, 3, 1]

new_y_train = [0, 3, 2, 1]

With this modification the dl model is working as the number of class matches with the dimension of one hot encoded value.

Is this the right way of approaching this problem? Also, could you let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the last layer of the model?

Comment: Still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The number of units for the last layer should match number of classes and number of classes should match the length of one hot encoding of the y_train. So if you have the following data for y_train

```
Y_train = [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

       [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]

       [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]

       [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

then the last layer of the model should be like this

```
model.add(Dense(6,activation="softmax"))
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: The number of class target I have is 4. Does keeping 6 at the output layer is a correct way?

Comment: If your class target number is 4 then change last model to Dense(4,activation="softmax") and also change the way you do one hot encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I've the feeling you don't really understand one-hot encoding. One hot encoding transforms a class (2) to 1s and 0s, that's the par you got, however your one-hot array is wrong.

```
  Y_train = [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

   [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]

   [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]

   [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

the way you wrote it means that it has 6 classes, and 4 datapoints, or 4 examples. What you want is:
've the feeling you don't really understand one-hot encoding. One hot encoding transforms a class (2) to 1s and 0s, that's the par you got, however your one-hot array is wrong.

```
Y_train = [[1. 0. 0. 0.]

           [0. 0. 0. 1.]

           [0. 1. 0. 0.]

           [0. 1. 0. 0. ]]
```

Now you have 4 classes, and this is what your error is complaining about.